# CUDA image processing error

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda, cimg

I am working on a small image processing project. I want to run a CUDA program that does image subtraction. So you have the image background and an image with the same background but with some other things on it. Once you subtract the to images you will get what's left. The two images are both of size 480*360 and my gpu is GTX780. My program throws an error  `./main': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x000000000126bd70 ***
Aborted (core dumped)` and the output image is wrong. I have been cracking my head to solve this. Here is the code:

The kernel:

```
__global__ void add(unsigned char* a, unsigned char* b, unsigned char* c, int numCols, int numWidth) {
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //Column
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; //Row
    if(i < numWidth && j < numCols)
    {
      int idx = j * numCols + i;
      c[idx] = b[idx] - a[idx];
    }   
}
```

and the main function:

```
int main() {
    CImg<unsigned char> img1("1.bmp");
    CImg<unsigned char> img2("2.bmp");
    //both images have the same size
    int width = img1.width();
    int height = img1.height();

    int size = width * height * 3; //both images of same size

    dim3 blockSize(16, 16, 1);
    dim3 gridSize((width + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x, (height + blockSize.y - 1) / blockSize.y, 1);

    unsigned char *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * (sizeof(unsigned char)));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * (sizeof(unsigned char)));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * (sizeof(unsigned char)));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, img1, size * (sizeof(unsigned char)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, img2, size * (sizeof(unsigned char)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    add<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dev_a, dev_b, dev_c, height, width);

    cudaMemcpy(img2, dev_c, size * (sizeof(unsigned char)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    img2.save("out.bmp");
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    return 0;
}
```

The image is loaded with the [CImg](http://cimg.eu/) library.

Comment: The line `int idx = j * numCols + i;` preceded by `j<numCols` looks suspicious. If `j` is your column index you should rather use `int idx = i * numCols + j;`.

Comment: @mman no its for the device. If it was on the host it would be plain malloc or new. The problem is in bytes i think somehow get less bytes allocated

Comment: That wouldn't crash your program, but either you are locating 3 times the memory needed or you are only calculating a third (you are using `size = width * height * 3` and then passing width and height as numWidth and numHeight.)

Comment: What is the size of img1? I mean sizeof ?

Comment: @mman `sizeof(imga1)` is 32 but because is a template pointer.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `img1.data()` instead of just `img1`  and `img2.data()` instead of just `img2` in the `cudaMemcpy` operations?  That [appears to be](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__storage.html) how a pointer to the underlying data is retrieved: " The address of this memory buffer can be retrieved by the function CImg<T>::data(). "

Comment: @RobertCrovella let me check this, thanks

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes you were correct! I have no idea how Cimg allocates memory. Funny thing is that when I defined the pointers as `int`, I got the same correct result as passing as a parameter the `img1.data()`. For a reason, the `Cimg()` allocates extra bytes behind the scene. Although I have no idea why it does it. Thank you again

Comment: @mman yes :) The `Cimg` does some allocations behind the scenes. I had to check the documentation.

Comment: @KostasRim: it would be helpful if you could accept the community wiki answer I added so this question drops off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag

Comment: @talonmies there you are.

Comment: @KostasRim: thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lay in the incorrect use of cimg containers in host code. According to the [documentation](http://cimg.eu/reference/group__cimg__storage.html), the image data pointer is accessed via the `data()` method, meaning that the `cudaMemcpy` calls in the host code should be supplied with  `img1.data()` and `img2.data()`.

[this answer was assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry]